# How do I integrate LUIS actions into my bot, prompting the user for more information?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm using a `LuisDialog`, and I would like to know how to use the `LuisResult` to detect the actions, parameters and prompt the user for the missing parameters. I know the `LuisResult` already contains the actions and parameters, however I don't know what is the best way to prompt the user, or how to send that information back to LUIS using the `contextId`. I wasn't able to find any example regarding this subject on the BotBuilder SDK or on the web in general.

Answer (score 1):

My rough approach would be this. For instance, you're expecting some entities in the `LuisResult`. If they're missing, you want to prompt the user for them.

First you'll check which entities are missing. If something is missing, prompt the user and redirect their response to another method that will process the new data. The LuisResult that was already received will need to be saved in `ConversationData` first.

```
        var requiredEntities = new List<string>()
        {
            "builtin.places.place_name",
            "builtin.places.place_type"
        };
        string askForMore = null;
        foreach(var entity in requiredEntities)
        {
            EntityRecommendation temp;
            var found = result.TryFindEntity(entity, temp);
            if (!found)
            {
                //Prompt the user for more information
                askForMore = entity;
            }
        }
        if (askForMore != null)
        {
            //TODO: store values from existing LuisResult for later use
            //For example, use ConversationData for storage.

            context.PostAsync("Please enter value for entity " + askForMore);
            context.Wait(AdditionalUserInputReceived);
        }
        else
        {
            //do normal stuff
        }
```

This is a fully manual way, I assume there could be more automation by combining `FormFlow` with a `LuisDialog`, but with less flexibility

Comment: Hi! So, that's actually the way I'm handling this kind of situation right now. I was just wondering if there is a way to directly implement LUIS actions because this code as it is completely ignores the LUIS actions (prompts and parameters). I know that this code get's things done (thank you) but I'm wondering if there's a better alternative where I can use the prompts and parameter names provided by LUIS.

Comment: To use Luis Actions, Use Luis Preview mode